# Persistent data storage of custom class

Tags: ios, swift3, data-modeling

I'm currently working on an project in iOS 10 trying to persistently store information of a bluetooth device. For the device to connect I need three variables of a custom class. For example:

```
var deviceInformation: BluetoothDeviceInfo?
```

These information should be globally available and modifyable, and persistent (so also when the app is killed).
I was thinking about using CoreData but it feels a little bit too much as there is maximum 1 device which is connected. Additionally, it's not that nice to store custom classes as core data model.
The other option would be a Singleton but the data would be lost when the app is quitted.
Lastly userdefaults would be an option but there I would have the same issue with the custom classes, wouldn't I?

Therefore, would be my question what is the best option in that case?

Comment: You can store custom class data in user defaults using NSCoding.

Comment: Do you really need to store the custom class?  Can't you just store the three values that are needed to re-create the classusijg basic types like `String`?  Then you can store the data simply in UserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a class named **CustomModel**

```
class CustomModel: NSObject, NSCoding {

var customArray : [SomeOtherCustomClass] = []

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()
    // Save your array or any custom objects s follows
    customArray = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "customArrayKey") as? [SomeOtherCustomClass] ?? []

}

// For getting info

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(customArray, forKey: "customArrayKey")
}
}
```

Now you custom class data will be persistent.

Let me know if you find any difficulty.